# What schema.org types does google knowledge graph api support?

Tags: python, google-api, semantic-web, schema.org, google-knowledge-graph

I am trying to run a [query](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1/?apix_params=%7B%22indent%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%22python%22%2C%22types%22%3A%5B%22ComputerLanguage%22%5D%7D) on the Google Knowledge Graph API to find the Python programming language and am having trouble specifying a type of [`ComputerLanguage`](https://schema.org/ComputerLanguage) or [`programmingLanguage`](https://schema.org/programmingLanguage). These are both valid schema.org types, but I receive a 400 error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I can't find any list of the types that Google Knowledge Graph API accepts. Am I specifying the type wrong, and is there a list of valid types somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: am looking at this. Do you have an API key?

Comment: Yes, I have an API key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `@ComputerLanguage` does not seem to be a `@Type` registered with GKG.

Alternatively `@SoftwareApplication` is a registered `@Type` so this query works:

`https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=Python&types=SoftwareApplication&key=` where you BYO key.

The search string does not appear to be case sensitive so either python or Python produces the same result.

Have tried alternative computer languages, such as JavaScript and C, and results are positive.

Tried a broader term (e.g. `@Intangible`) but GKG does not appear to generate results for broad-terms, only leaf-node terms.

Interestingly, if you do not specify `types` you will get a comprehensive response that does NOT include `ComputerLanguage` e.g. `https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=Python&key=`

If you use `https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=JavaScript&key=` you get `@Book` and `@Event` primarily but no `@ComputerLanguage`

Will ping the Google API team to learn why `@ComputerLanguage` is not in their search vocabulary.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like there is no Python entity, which dbpedia and wikidata both have.